# Clean retry in deferred.defer

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using `deferred.defer` quite heavily to schedule tasks using push queues on AppEngine.

Sometimes I wish I would have a clean way to signal a retry for a task without having to raise an Exception that generates a `log warning`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you raise a `deferred.SingularTaskFailure` it will set an error HTTP-status, but there won't be an exception in the log.

Answer (score 0):

Just relaunch the task from the task with another `deferred.defer` call.

Comment: @marcadian there is no `self` in this context.

Comment: maybe change to use taskqueue and Class so you have `self`? :P